# Is there any way to wait for a PostMessage to be processed by the recipient?

Tags: c#, winapi, message-queue

I encounter the problem, that after posting some WM_KEYDOWN/WM_KEYUP messages, I need to use Thread.Sleep for like at least 200ms, before then to post WM_LMOUSEDOWN/WM_LMOUSEUP messages. If I don't do this, the recipient processes the mouse click first, which means the earlier keystrokes go to the wrong position of the target handle.
I cannot use SendMessage, because the recipient ignores those as WM_KEYDOWN/WM_KEYUP.

Is there any way to wait for a PostMessage to be processed?

Comment: Why must you fake input?

Comment: Er, for UI automation there is UIAutomation

Comment: No, the app I am writing should be able to work with any gui, e.g. flash or java applications.. why is that even important?

Comment: One wonders why the target app processes queued messages out of order

Comment: Exactly. That's why I'm asking this question.

Comment: Impossible for us to guess. Ask the author of the target app, whatever it is.

Comment: So you imply that question would be necessary to solve this one? Why is that? However, the target is of class "Internet Explorer_Server". And my guess is, it has different message queues for different types of messages.

Comment: A thread has one single message queue. Your rejection of UIautomation seems odd

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60422/discussion-between-xamid-and-david-heffernan).

Comment: You have 2 options: Contact the author of the target application and ask for details about their message handling, or use [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx). There is no safe way for an application to guess how another application handles its input. The fact that a thread has a single FIFO input queue does not allow for any assumptions on the order of message **handling**.

Comment: I found indeed no way. But fortunately, for this little piece, I could use the UI Automation framework, since the login was not flash itself.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to wait for a PostMessage to be processed?

No there is not. There is no API that allows you to wait until or be notified that a posted message has been processed by its recipient.

Comment: However, there is [`SendMessageCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644951.aspx) which does essentially that. Even though the message is not posted (and thus moved to the front of the input queue), the effect is the same when used across threads, as far as the target application is concerned. Instead of retrieving the first message from the queue, the call to `GetMessage` dispatches all queue up messages **sent** from other threads, before moving forward to retrieve the first message from the message queue.

Comment: @IInspectable It's not really comparable. Sent messages are dispatched direct to the window procedure. Posted messages are pulled out by a call to `GetMessage`, and dealt with in the message loop. Which often, but not necessarily, calls `TranslateMessage` and then `DispatchMessage`. Hard to know for sure what the target app is, or is doing.

Comment: Sent messages are queued up as all, when `SendMessage` crosses threads. They are not immediately dispatched, and also require a call to `GetMessage`/`PeekMessage` to be dispatched. When crossing threads, `SendMessageNotify` (or `SendMessageCallback`) and `PostMessage` are pretty much identical.

Comment: @IInspectable What I mean is that if the target app deals with certain input messages directly, rather than calling `DispatchMessage`, then that code won't execute if input messages are sent rather than posted.

Comment: When crossing threads, **sent** messages are queued up, and dispatched as part of the call to `GetMessage`/`PeekMessage`. This may cause applications that would rather not dispatch certain (input) messages to fail, while **posted** messages will be handled properly. Your explanation of the effect is correct, while the intricacies that cause it are slightly inaccurate.

Comment: @IInspectable I think I have been accurate, but perhaps you have not understood what I said. I do believe that I have a good understanding of how messages are delivered and dispatched.

Comment: To claim there would be no way attests a lack of understanding in computer science. There has to be a way, since this is obviously not an undecidable problem. We just have no solution.

Comment: I don't concur. If the system doesn't offer a mechanism to do something, where does computer science come into matters. With a different system design things could be different. But here we are talking about Win32. I wonder if this question is related to your other question today.

Comment: If a system doesn't offer a mechanism to do X, one could still implement a mechanism to do X, which would change the system.
My questions are related in a way that they are concerning the same program.

Comment: In this case the system doesn't offer you the hooks

Comment: For example, one could subclass the target and hack the desired functionality in. Look [here](http://www.fengyuan.com/article/wmprint.html) for an example to do stuff like that, which in your way of thinking should be impossible. But obviously (for computer scientists at least) there would be infinitely more ways to accomplish that. Such as hacking the windows message system and providing a new communication layer, or providing an assembler spy application that is able to interprete which messages are being processed. However, such is too much effort for the practical implementation.

Comment: Obviously you can hack. But that's not really what we are talking about. The assumption is that you stay within the bounds of the system provided api.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan so is there some solution here, could you please take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377689/wait-for-the-result-of-postmessage-win32

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SetWindowsHookEx` with `WH_GETMESSAGE`.

The `CALLBACK` function `MsgProc` insides a **dll**  will notify your application about any message that is going to be processed by the target application and all other applications.

You can also inject some shellcode using `VirtualAllocEx` and `WriteProcessMemory` that notifies your application about the message that the target application is going to process.

Then use `SetWindowLongPtr` with `GWLP_WNDPROC` to modify the window procedure to point to the injected shell code and make sure that the injected shell code at last `CallWindowProc` to the return value of `GetWindowLongPtr` with `GWLP_WNDPROC`.

Obviously that `GetWindowLongPtr` with `GWLP_WNDPROC` should be called first before `SetWindowLongPtr` with `GWLP_WNDPROC`.

Your application can also `DebugActiveProcess` the target application and insert a breakpoint at the address returned by `GetWindowLongPtr` with `GWLP_WNDPROC`.

When the target application dispatches a message and calls the window procedure, the target application reaches the breakpoint, notifies your application that the target application has reached a breakpoint and then the target application becomes suspended.

At this time your application can call `GetThreadContext` to retrieve the four parameters on the stack frame of the thread that reached the breakpoint.

These four parameters are exactly the message that the target application is about to process.

If both `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP` in the target application invoke only one function with exactly one UINT parameter and if you succeed to find the entry point of these functions then `CreateRemoteThread` with `WaitForSingleObject` may work as well.

Comment: It has been a while since I gave up on this problem because I did not want to use complicated hacking techniques. I did not look deeply into your possible solution, but doesn't it only consider sent messages instead of posted messages? As I wrote: "I cannot use SendMessage, because the recipient ignores those as WM_KEYDOWN/WM_KEYUP" If you still think your solution works, you might want to consult David Heffernan, who posted an answer which directly contradicts yours.

Answer (score -2):

Yes there is: just use `SendMessage` instead of `PostMessage` (Please note that SendMessage poses a deadlock risk when used by a different thread and the GUI thread by chance waits on this thread for any reason)

Generally: If you need to fake input you should never post the messages yourself. Instead you should use `SendInput()`

Comment: As I wrote, it needed to be PostMessage, since SendMessage is ignored by the target app.

Comment: this is not the answer, SendMessage is bad and may lead to memory problems etc. (it is not waiting any other messages)

Comment: @vtz SendMessage works correctly. It is an essential part of Win32. Any problems you face are due to defects in your own code, misuse of SendMessage etc.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you are correct, regarding my question, the issue was not using SendMessage and the string variable, when i changed it with char text buffer and then using SendMessage was what i needed. Thanks!